# Show div with same id, but different class?

Tags: javascript

According to w3 standards there should not be divs with the same ID (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). But, I'm trying to use this overlay effect: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/ with multiple buttons. I have searched the web (and stack) and found few topics about the subject.

The overlay is triggered with

```
<p><button id="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
```

And the js  for that is  `var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' )`

My thoughts is to go from a ID to a class. So i can call the overlay with

```
<p><button class="trigger-overlay-1" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
<p><button class="trigger-overlay-2" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
<p><button class="trigger-overlay-3" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
...
```

Here is the current js

```
(function() {
            var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
                overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
                closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
                transEndEventNames = {
                    'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                    'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
                    'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
                    'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
                    'transition': 'transitionend'
                },
                transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
                support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

            function toggleOverlay() {
                if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
                    classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
                    classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
                    var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                        if( support.transitions ) {
                            if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                            this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                        }
                        classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
                    };
                    if( support.transitions ) {
                        overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                    }
                    else {
                        onEndTransitionFn();
                    }
                }
                else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
                    classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
                }
            }

            triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
            closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
        })()

    ;
```

Im trying to change it to `var triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay-1, trigger-overlay-2' ),`

But getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'triggerBttn.addEventListener')`.

**Q Update**

The answer given by @davidnortonjr is the answer I stuck with. But, the button is not triggering the right menu´s. First button works, but button two and three is not triggering right div (triggering first div/menu).

```
<!-- Should open first overlay menu -->
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
<!-- Should open second overlay menu -->
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
```

Here is menu HTML (sorry for leaving that out in first q

```
<!-- FIRST OVERLAY MENU -->
    <div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
        <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="menuitem1">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a class="menuitem2">Item2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- SECOND OVERLAY MENU -->
    <div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
        <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="menuitem1">Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a class="menuitem2">Item1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ j08691: Probably wishful thinking... the jQuery equivalent will be a fraction of the code-size :)

Comment: Why don't you just use the same class for all the buttons if you want to select all of them by class name? Just remove the suffixes?

Comment: Could it be the comma in getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay-1, trigger-overlay-2' )?

Comment: Notice the `s` in `document.getElementsByClassName`. It does not return **one** element. It returns an array-like object of all elements with that class. To get the first one, use `document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0]` and so on...

Comment: @HannesJohansson your are free to convert it! (jättesnäll också=))

Comment: Both answers suggest doing it the way I meant. That should solve the problem described in the question. If there are other problems, I guess you'll have to post a new question, or update this question to show what it is you really mean.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements can have the same name, so I would assign them all the same class name. You should create the buttons this way:

```
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
```

Then assign triggerButtons (no need to drop vowels):

```
var triggerButtons = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' )
```

That is an array, so then you would loop over it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < triggerButtons.length; i++) {
    triggerButtons[i].addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
}
```

Comment: This first overlay is showing `<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">`, but not the second or third (same class everything)

Comment: Ah. you'd have to have an attribute on the buttons like data-overlay-target="overlay-1" then in the toggleOverlay function you'd have to get the overlay by ID, based on the event target's overlay-target. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector doesn't match any elements and `undefined` is returned.

If I understand correctly you're trying to bind a click handler on each element that can trigger an overlay.

Your css classes suggest that you should be using ids instead. That way each button can be uniquely identified but they can also share a same behaviour or style through a common class name:

```html
<button id="trigger-1" class="trigger">...</button>
<button id="trigger-2" class="trigger">...</button>
<button id="trigger-3" class="trigger">...</button>
```

This would make looking up and binding your triggers much easier to write:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button.trigger'), function (trigger) {
  trigger.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //your code here
  });
});
```

Note that if you have a lot of those elements, event delegation might be worth looking into.